# Android: generate views dynamically from database

Tags: android

My goal is to collect health and family related data through interview some patients. So I'll provide every information about every view or question in database. like view type (radio button,edit text ,spinner...), data type (text or number), data length, whether it has any media (image, audio, video) regarding this question. Questions might have a dependency (visibility or value) on other question. I have tried so far and what I got that for small number of questions its okay. But when its about 100 or 150 or more questions, performance is not good. Since I am running lots of sql query and refreshing view manually. I mean on event (onSelect, onChange, onChecked.....) I am saving data to db, changing other question's visibility, value. So far lots of requirement have been added to my app. Can you suggest me about coding structure , library so that I can improve the performance? What are the things that should be used in this app? I have attached some pictures so that you can get a idea.
View Demo https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCGuz.png

Dependency https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2nzj.png

Required field validation https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuOH.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Firebase services. There are some huge advantages compared to sql especially with app development. It's optimized for many queries and therefore it's speed is impressive. You can just a Firebase account and use it(Although with limited resources). I would really that you add the firebase library to your project. Also with sensible health and personal data should stay private and as far as I know there are literally always security issues with Apache2 or nginx or php or mysql/mariadb so just do it the easy more reliable and more secure way. I hope I helped you out. :)

Comment: ok i got your point. Firebase will improve the database performance.But what about my code performance. What am I missing?